# How many of a resource do I need to keep villagers happy?

Tags: against-the-storm

Having enough of a complex food increases villagers resolve, as do services. When exactly are these resources consumed and how much do I need?

Answer (score 1):

The in-game encyclopedia says that:
Villagers will consume one food item per break, and species have different break intervals (1:40 to 2:00).

I assume they'll also consume one service item per break. I'm not sure how long these items last until running out.

There's factors that affect time between breaks, as well as season length, so it's difficult to say how much you'll need per day. I think the stronger approach is to limit the amount you'll make under the recipes (shortcut: u) panel.

Edit: I've since learned that they will consume one of each complex preferred food (if available) per break. This looks to be the same for available service items.
You could use Consumption Control (hotkey: i) once unlocked to limit them to only one complex food. I haven't found a need to do this, but it's a small optimization.

Comment: Keep in mind there's a resolve penalty for forbidding services/complex food/clothes when they're available. It's only an additional -1 or -2, but that can add up.